# Update a simple boolean with ngrx reducer

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, redux-reducers

i'm learning NGRX and i don't know what i miss for update a state value from a model with the reducer.

First i have this model:

```
export interface GlobalModel {
  navigation: Navigation
}

export interface Navigation {
  isNavOpen: boolean,
}
```

I have define this actions *global.actions.ts*:

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { GlobalModel } from "./global.models";

export enum Types {
  NAV_OPEN = '[Global] NAV: open',
  NAV_CLOSE = '[Global] NAV: close',
}

export class NavOpen implements Action {
  readonly type = Types.NAV_OPEN;
  constructor(public payload: GlobalModel) {}
}

export class NavClose implements Action {
  readonly type = Types.NAV_CLOSE;
  constructor(public payload: GlobalModel) {}
}

export type All = NavOpen |  NavClose;
```

And in the reducer i want to passing true or false the isNavOpen boolean

```
import { GlobalModel } from "./global.models";
import * as fromAction from './global.actions';

export interface GlobalState {
  entities: GlobalModel;
}

const initialState: GlobalState = {
  entities: null,
}

export function reducer (
  state = initialState,
  action: fromAction.All
) : GlobalState {

  switch(action.type) {

    case fromAction.Types.NAV_OPEN: {
      return {...state, entities: action.payload }
    }

    case fromAction.Types.NAV_CLOSE: {
      return {...state, entities: action.payload }
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why is the state so nested? It's makes it hard to update/select state.
You could use [ngrx-immer](https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-immer) to make it easier...

I also don't understand the question, and the snippet should work.
To update state in your case you need to update the nested property, but since the action contains the full `GlobalModel` it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question is actually if i use the NAV_OPEN action nothing change because my model is never updated.
Where and how can i change the nested property to true?
I'm not sure of what i need to do that.

Comment: You're already doing that action.payload should contain an object that has `isNavOpen: false/true`